# Prevent new customers (never purchased anything before) from ordering specific products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, orders, customer

I am in a situation that requires to prevent new customers (who never purchased before) from placing an order that contains some specific products.

These products should be available for all customers (logged in and not logged in), however when checking out, new customers shouldn't be able to complete and should receive  a custom error message.

Is there any extension that allow that?

*Additional information: the story behind this is that these products are actually refills products, and should be only available to previous customers.

Thank you

Comment: I doubt that there is such extension. But not hard to make one. Just check if customer is guest or logged in, check if have orders from earlier, and on add to quote check if product in list of those specific items (can be attribute for product). If so, do not add to cart and show message.

Comment: For example product ids 1 and 2. So no new customer should be able to buy this products(1 & 2). Only customers who have purchased 1 can buy 1 not 2 and if he/she has purchased 2 can buy 2 but not 1. is it correct?